# something like is_childtheme()

Tags: child-theme

in the functions.php of a parent theme, I would like to check for wheter the theme is being run directly, or it is run via a child theme.

Is there a conventional way of doing this?
I cant find the is_childtheme() function I would have liked to have found.. so whats the best way? Check for theme name and compare it to parent theme's maybe? how can this be done?

Comment: Now I simply check if get_current_theme() != 'ParentThemeName'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As One Trick Pony said, there's a dedicated function (since WP 3.0):

[is_child_theme()](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/theme.php?rev=17640#L9)

Answer (score 3):

WordPress Core does it like this (at least, at one point):

```
if( TEMPLATEPATH !== STYLESHEETPATH )
  // We have a child theme active
```

Comment: I think it's available in 3.1 as `is_child_theme()`

Comment: Same thing I was going to suggest: compare `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` and `get_template_directory_uri()`.

Comment: I was going to suggest something similar... `get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) == get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' )` ... :) +1